# The Necessity of a Disclaimer

Tags: blog, legal, articles

I am a blogger. I write science articles. I study science and write articles in my blog in simple words for the general public to understand. Does this require a disclaimer as I do not want to see something like the following in my inbox

> I read your blog and damaged something. Pay me compensation.

Comment: You are asking for legal advice. This will likely vary depending on where you live. You should consult a lawyer!  That said, there can not be any harm in having a disclaimer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimers are not legally binding anyway.  Having a disclaimer does little to protect you from a lawsuit.  Not having one does nothing.

As long as you write responsibly then few judges are going to allow a case like this against you since the reader is the one who made the changes.  But a disclaimer gives them an easy out to just toss the case.

Chances are the average user is not going to prevail in court should you choose to fight it.  But the disclaimer might save you the hassle in the first place, or reduce your out of pocket expenses should someone decide to sue you anyway.

Comment: One thing is that I write absolutely original content. The content is always beneficial. So I was thinking about a disclaimer especially when I write health articles.